# org.hibernate.mapping.Table.getColumn returns null

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, h2

I am trying to make junit tests and testing repositories. For that I need to create test database use `h2` database, the test class looks:

*PokemonRepositoryTest.java*:

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "spring.flyway.enabled=false",
        "spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=com.example.j2.config.H2PhysicalNamingStrategy"
})
public class PokemonRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private PokemonRepository pokemonRepository;

    @Test
    public void saved_pokemon_is_not_null(){
        // arrange
        Pokemon pokemon = Pokemon.builder()
                .name("pikachu")
                .type("electric")
                .build();
        // act
        Pokemon saved = pokemonRepository.save(pokemon);
        // assert
        Assert.notNull(saved,"saved pokemon is null");
        Assert.isTrue(saved.getId() > 0, "saved pokemon is not grater then 0");
    }
}
```

Now I have a entity called `User` having physical (table) name as `user`. However this is [not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70797504/spring-data-jpa-h2-database-is-returning-ddl-error-during-table-creation) as `user` (not quoted, thus H2 uppercases it to `USER`) is reserved keyword. So I decided to implement `PhysicalNamingStrategy` to prefix all tables created by H2 (again, this is for test purposes, in my development I am using mysql which does not have `user` as keyword and thus is fine):

*H2PhysicalNamingStrategy.java*:

```
@Configuration
public class H2PhysicalNamingStrategy implements PhysicalNamingStrategy {
    private static final String TABLE_PREFIX = "_";
    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalCatalogName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        return identifier;
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalSchemaName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        return identifier;
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        return Identifier.toIdentifier(TABLE_PREFIX + identifier.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalSequenceName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        return identifier;
    }

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        return identifier;
    }
}
```

Now I am getting error:

```
...
Hibernate: drop table if exists _pokemon cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists _refresh_token cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists _review cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists _role cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists _user cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists _user_roles cascade 
Hibernate: create table _pokemon (id bigint generated by default as identity, name varchar(255), type varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table _refresh_token (id bigint generated by default as identity, user_id bigint, token varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table _review (stars integer, id bigint generated by default as identity, pokemon_id bigint, title varchar(255), content clob, primary key (id))
2024-01-07T01:31:07.894+01:00 ERROR 132222 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Error creating SQL 'create' commands for table '_role' [Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.mapping.Column.isUnique()" because the return value of "org.hibernate.mapping.Table.getColumn(org.hibernate.mapping.Column)" is null]
```

It says `org.hibernate.mapping.Table.getColumn` is null. But why?

EDIT:
changed prefix to suffix (as suggested by @Basil Bourque in comments):

*H2PhysicalNamingStrategy.java*:

```
@Configuration
public class H2PhysicalNamingStrategy implements PhysicalNamingStrategy {
 private static final String TABLE_SUFFIX = "_";
 ...
 @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier identifier, JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
        return Identifier.toIdentifier(identifier.getText() + TABLE_SUFFIX);
    }
 ...
}
```

but still the same error:

```
...
Hibernate: drop table if exists pokemon_ cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists refresh_token_ cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists review_ cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists role_ cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists user_ cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists user_roles_ cascade 
Hibernate: create table pokemon_ (id bigint generated by default as identity, name varchar(255), type varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table refresh_token_ (id bigint generated by default as identity, user_id bigint, token varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table review_ (stars integer, id bigint generated by default as identity, pokemon_id bigint, title varchar(255), content clob, primary key (id))
2024-01-07T13:36:53.866+01:00 ERROR 3851 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Error creating SQL 'create' commands for table 'role_' [Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.mapping.Column.isUnique()" because the return value of "org.hibernate.mapping.Table.getColumn(org.hibernate.mapping.Column)" is null]
```

EDIT2:
here is full source code:
[github](https://github.com/shepherd123456/SO_h2_db_when_testing)

Comment: “user” is only the tip of an iceberg of a problem. Across various databases, over a thousand words are in use as keywords, reserved words, etc. So it is shockingly easy to run into a naming conflict. Interestingly, the SQL standard explicitly promises to never use a trailing underscore in any of its keywords. So I suggest always naming all your database objects (tables, columns, indexes, etc.) with a trailing underscore. This eliminates an entire class of bizarre confusing errors. Example: `user_`.

Comment: changed the prefix to suffix (as you suggest), still the same error, see edit to OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to incorrect column name specified in the [unique constraint](https://github.com/shepherd123456/SO_h2_db_when_testing/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/j2/entity/Role.java#L19) in `Role` class. The column name in the constraint is `roleName`, but the [actual field name](https://github.com/shepherd123456/SO_h2_db_when_testing/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/j2/entity/Role.java#L25) and hence the column name is `name`. You need to either update the column name in the unique constraint from `roleName` to `name` or change the field name from `name` to `roleName`.

Comment: I was refactoring and did not synced fields and annotations